# How is it inheritance different from association when it comes to memory layout

Tags: c#, memory, layout

I have a basic question,
How is inheritance different from association when it comes to memory layout.

```
class BaseClass{
 private int i;
 public void DoSomethinG(){} 
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
}

class AssocClass {
private BaseClass bClass = new BaseClass();
}
```

Other than access restriction to private members ,I believe both DerivedClass and AssocClass are same. Memory for variable i in BaseClass is allocated in both  the cases the size of DerivedClass and AssocClasss should be same.

Am I right in my assumption or am I missing something trivial ?

Regards,
Jeez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory layout is different between the two. With `DerivedClass` the data from both `DerivedClass` and `BaseClass` will be stored together. You can't have an instance of `DerivedClass` without also having an implicit instance of `BaseClass`.

`AssocClass` has a reference to an instance of `BaseClass`. This could be null so there may be no instance at all. If there is an instance, it is a separate object that is stored somewhere else. E.g. it could be in a different generation of the heap. This also means that the instances could be garbage collected independently (provided of course that the instance of `AssocClass` doesn't reference the instance of `BaseClass`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Brian, you are true the instance in case of association can be in a different generation

Comment: @Jeez: It could be in a different generation, but with the code in your example it wouldn't. If you hold on to an instance of AssocClass through a garbage collection and the assign a new object to the bClass reference then the instance of `AssocClass` will be in an older generation than the instance of `BaseClass`.